# How to save color in uwp using Settings Storage?

Tags: string, colors, uwp

---

I want to save border color in UWP using Setting Storage.

### Any ideas?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the color as string: use `ToString` method of the `Color` class to convert the color to string and the `ColorHelper.ToColor()` from the [UWP Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/) to convert back:

```
    private void SaveColor(Color color)
    {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        localSettings.Values["color"] = color.ToString();
    }
    private Color LoadColor()
    {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        return Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Helpers.ColorHelper.ToColor((string) localSettings.Values["color"]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!